# iTerm2: Split pane - coloured title bar instead of dimming

Tags: iterm

In iTerm2 it is possible, to split panes. Thus, I have parallel multiple terminals instead (or in addition) to tabs.
This is very similar to the i3 Window Manager or Terminator Terminal Emulator.

When having multiple terminals, I would like to quickly know what is the active terminal. iTerm2 has an option to dim, but this is not so great because inactive terminals are not that good to read (e.g. htop).

It seems there is no option of using coloured title bars (not tabs!) based on active pane/terminal. Only programms can do so via escape codes). Does anybody know a hack for this or is up to me to request an enhancement? Maybe I overlooked it...

Thanks,
Timo

Comment: I use a very slight dimming so it's not so hard to read inactive splits but it's still easy to distinct what session is active.

Comment: Hi Igor - ja, the same for me currently. However, the light situation in the office sometimes makes it hard to see the difference. Dimming more also is an issue for me - that is why such feature would be great.